# Is QnAMaker service deployable as cognitive service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-qna-maker

We are creating a bot using QnAMaker service and would like to know if we can deploy the service as a cognitive service in our own azure subscription. Currently, we do not see the option to deploy it in custom azure subscription and it seems QnA Maker is deployed by itself.

Is QnA Maker service deployed in multiple regions?

The question arises as we would like to know the deployment and load balancing of the QnAMaker service to better optimize our bot deployment.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: I created a QnA Maker service, created a NodeJS bot using sample QnA Maker example. Created Bot in dev.botframework.com. I am looking for option of deploying QnAMaker service as a deployable on azure portal so that I can deploy it in 2 regions east and west and control which NodeJS app goes to which region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QnA Maker is GA since May 7, 2018. With GA the architecture of QnA Maker changed.

> QnA Maker announced General Availability on May 7, 2018 at the \build\ conference. QnA Maker GA has a new architecture built on Azure. Knowledge bases created with QnA Maker Free Preview will need to be migrated to QnA Maker GA. QnA Maker Preview will be deprecated in November 2018. For more information about the changes in QnA Maker GA, see the QnA Maker GA announcement [blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/05/07/announcing-general-availability-of-qnamaker/).

You are now forced to host QnA Maker on you own Azure subscription which will provision a bunch of azure resources and of course will cost money now.

In case you need to migrate your existing preview QnA Maker, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/tutorials/migrate-knowledge-base) is the documentation for it.

> Is QnA Maker service deployed in multiple regions?

No, right now QnA Maker API is only available in [westus region](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff). However, the resources provisioned by QnA Maker, mainly Azure Search under the hood, are available in many other regions. So while the API endpoint it self is in westus, the rest of your resources can be hosted in other regions.

Disclaimer: I'm not working for Microsoft, so this information might be out-of-date already. Maybe somebody from Microsoft can confirm all of this.